# 500 Internal Server error when PUT in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, laravel-5

**PROBLEM**

Hello, long time ago I got 500 Internal Server Error when I use method PUT in angularjs (I'm trying to update list name), but still don't know how to fix it and make update work properly. At the moment i'm manually set value to update. I got that error, but when I refresh page, then lists name is changed to that value. Seems like angular don't work properly and after put, it don't give `.success`, but give me `.error`, because of what I can't use my GET method.

So at the moment I can set list name for example "Grocery List", hit button edit, hit enter (because I set new list name value in angular manually) and get error. After page refresh I will get same "Grocery List", but with new name "Test". I need single page application, so I can't use refresh, but GET method after PUT method don't work. Any ideas how to make it work? Please help me!

**ERROR**

When I'm changed list name and hit enter in console shows error 
`PUT http://localhost/anydo/anydocopy/anydocopy/public/lists/1 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I checked Network->Preview in google chrome and there shows `UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`. So anybody know where is problem?

**CODE**

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
    Route::get('tasks', 'TasksController@index');
    Route::get('lists', 'ListsController@index');
    Route::get('lists/{id}', 'ListsController@show');
    Route::post('lists', 'ListsController@store');
    Route::put('lists/{id}', 'ListsController@update');
    Route::post('lists/{id}', 'TasksController@store');
    Route::delete('lists/{id}', 'ListsController@delete');
    });
```

midleware cors.php

```
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, x-xsrf-token, X-Requested-With'
        );
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

controller

```
public function update($id, CreateListsRequest $request)
{
    $response = Lists::findorfail($id)->update($request->all());

    return Response($response, 201);
}
```

angular

```
  $scope.updatel = function($event){
            console.log($event.keyCode);
            console.log($scope.editlist);
            if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
                var list = {
                  name: 'Test'
                };

                $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: 'http://localhost/anydo/anydocopy/anydocopy/public/lists/1',
                    data: list
                })
                    .success(function () {
                        console.log('true');
                        $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'http://localhost/anydo/anydocopy/anydocopy/public/lists'
                        })
                            .success(function (d) {
                                console.log(d);
                                $scope.listsdata = d;
                            });
                    })
                     .error(function () {
                     console.log(list);
                     console.log('false');

                    });
```

html

```
 <div ng-repeat="lists in listsdata.lists">
                    <div id="DIV_24" close-on-outside-click="div.popup_information">
                        <button ng-click="lists.show = !lists.show" id="MORE_BUTTON">:</button>
                        <div class="popup_information" ng-show="lists.show">
                                <button id="DELETE_BUTTON" ng-click="del_list(lists)">X</button>
                                <button id="EDIT_BUTTON" ng-click="edbut.show = !edbut.show">E</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" id="edit" ng-model="editlist" ng-show="edbut.show" ng-keydown="updatel($event)" onkeydown="hideshow(document.getElementById('edit'))" class="form-control" style="font:24px bold;" value="{{lists.name}}" />
                        <a href="#/{{lists.id}}">
                            <div id="DIV_25">
                                <label class="test" style="font-weight: normal" ng-show="!edbut.show" close-on-outside-click="test">{{lists.name}} </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="DIV_26">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

I know that mby too much code, but I don't understand how to fix this error and where I did mistake, so I just give you all code I'm working with. If need any other code, please ask in comments.

**WHAT I TRYED ALREADY**

I just change `.success` to `.error` and `.error` to `.success` and now all work like it must, but I still get same error. At the moment `GET` method in angular work when I get `.error`, what is wrong. Mby someone could help me and make solution why I get error after `PUT` method.

**RESPONSE.PHP**

This function is on 403 line.

```
 public function setContent($content)
    {
        if (null !== $content && !is_string($content) && !is_numeric($content) && !is_callable(array($content, '__toString'))) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "%s" given.', gettype($content)));
        }

        $this->content = (string) $content;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Your PHP error message seems to be really clear about what your issue is.

Comment: Explain please then, and tell me how to fix it.

Comment: I don't know where I set boolean, if I define  `var list = {name: 'Test'};` what is string and then I send `data: list` what is string as well. So where I send boolean? Please explain me how you understand that message, because I don't understand where i send boolean.

Comment: I'm guessing it originates from this line: `$response = Lists::findorfail($id)->update($request->all());` If you're passing a boolean (`$response`) to `return Response($response, 201);`, then `Response` is telling you not to pass a boolean, pass a string instead.

Comment: Ok, and how to change `$response` to string then?

Comment: Minimally, `return Response(json_encode($response), 201);`, which will produce the text `true` or `false`.

Comment: Omg, thanks so much guys, `return Response (var_export($response), 201);` and all works fine.